# How do I get rid of an error in my php.code?

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to make a login function working with php. For some reason erros keep showing up when I load the page.

```
<html>
<?php

   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $SQL)or die(mysqli_error($connection));
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];
      $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

     if (!$dbc || mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>

<html/>
```

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/website/login.php on line 13

Comment: You should not store plain text passwords. Hash them. What are `$con`, `$connection`, and `$dbc`? Why have 3 db connections?

Comment: `$db` must be the correct variable, since you didn't get an error from `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Change `$con` and `$dbc` to `$db`.

Comment: `session_register()` does not exists in PHP since PHP 5.4.0. If you are still using that PHP version, you should think about upgrading immediately. If you are already on latest version, then this will throw an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
mysqli_query($con, $SQL)
```

Your `$con`variable has not been initialized, so it’s null. That’s what your error message says `null given ... on line 13`

Try to add a

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

before line 13. `$connection`and `$dbc` seem redundant, don’t use them.

In PHP, Variable names are case-sensitive. This means $SQL is not the same as $sql. The second parameter in `mysqli_query($con, $SQL)` is also null. Use `$sql`.

It seems you combined lines from different books or tutorials. Follow a single tutorial until you have understood what each line does and why it’s there. If a tutorial doesn’t work for you, try another one. Some of them are not good.